# Can't show values from my view using mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, mysql2

I did a query in MySql but is not working Rails so I installed mysql2 gem.

Here is the information:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adb8/6
```

The query is working fine without problems and showing this result:

```
 UNIT  V1  A1  N1   V2 A2  N2   V3  A3  N3   V4  A4  N4   V5  A5  N5
 LIFE  2   0   0    1   2  0    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
 ROB   0   1   0    0   1  2    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
```

-Installed mysql2 gem for rails 2.3.8

```
gem install mysql2 -v0.2.6
```

-Created the controller:

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController

   def index
      @result =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select distinct @sql := concat('SELECT pb.name as unit,',group_concat(concat('SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v',id,',SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a',id,',SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n',id)),' FROM cia_ensures ce LEFT JOIN policies p on ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id  INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id AND ca.id=1  Group by p.policy_business_unit_id') from cia_ensures where id in(1,2,3,4,5);")
      @result2 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("prepare stmt from @sql;")
      @result3 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("execute stmt;")
   end

end
```

-Created the view:

```
<% @result.each do |policy| %>
   <%= policy.try(:unit) %>
   <%= policy.try(:v1) %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the log:

```
SQL (0.9ms)   select distinct @sql := concat('SELECT pb.name as unit,',group_concat(concat('SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v',id,',SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a',id,',SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n',id)),' FROM cia_ensures ce LEFT JOIN policies p on ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id AND ca.id=1 Group by p.policy_business_unit_id') from cia_ensures where id in(1,2,3,4,5);
SQL (0.9ms)   prepare stmt from @sql;
SQL (0.2ms)   execute stmt;
```

And I got this error in the view:

```
undefined method `unit' for #<Array:0x7f0e668cbf88>
```

Tried changing values from my view to this:

```
<% @result2.each do |policy| %>
   <%= policy.try(:unit) %>
   <%= policy.try(:v1) %>
<% end %>
```

And got this error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

Tried again changing values from my view to this:

```
<% @result3.each do |policy| %>
   <%= policy.try(:unit) %>
   <%= policy.try(:v1) %>
<% end %>
```

And got this error:

```
undefined method `unit' for #<Array:0x7f0e66b67aa8>
```

Tried again changing values from my view to this:

```
<% @result3.each do |policy| %>
   <%= policy.try(:unit) %>
   <%= policy.try(:v1) %>
<% end %>
```

I can't show or get values from my query ,is there any way to show values?

```
 UNIT  V1  A1  N1   V2 A2  N2   V3  A3  N3   V4  A4  N4   V5  A5  N5
 LIFE  2   0   0    1   2  0    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
 ROB   0   1   0    0   1  2    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
```

According with a friend this code will work but how can I do to show all this without writing lots of lines?

```
<% @result3.each do |policy| %>
   <%= policy[0] %>
   <%= policy[1] %>
   <%= policy[2] %>
   <%= policy[3] %>
   <%= policy[4] %>
   <%= policy[5] %>
   <%= policy[6] %>
   <%= policy[7] %>
   ....
<%end%>
```

Please I spent one month without finding an answer and still can't get values.

Please somebody can help me with this?

I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think `@result3` is the one you want, since it's executing the query.

```
undefined method `unit' for #<Array:0x7f0e66b67aa8>
```

This is telling you `try` found the object to be non-nil, and tried to call the `#unit` method on the object.  That seems unlikely to work with a MySQL result set.

I've never used the mysql2, but a quick google shows its result object is a hash-like object with keys of the column names OR just straight numeric indices like an array, so try something like this:

```
<% @result3.each do |policy| %>
   <%= policy['unit'] %>
   <%= policy['v1'] %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% @result3.each do |policy| %>
   <%= policy['UNIT'] %>
   <%= policy['V1'] %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% @result3.each do |policy| %>
   <%= policy[0] %>
   <%= policy[1] %>
<% end %>
```

And if that doesn't work, at the very least just try this to see what you're getting back:

```
<% @result3.each do |policy| %>
   <%= policy.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  Yeah the numbers are not great, I would think it would have string keys for the columns as well.  Try my last suggestion with `<%= policy.inspect %>`, it should dump the object out and show you everything, might help.

Comment: According [to the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.15/frames) the result row object should have a `fields` method that may also provide some useful information.

Comment: `inspect` isn't going to be something you'd want to use for real, it's just a debugging tool.

Comment: I assume it's possible but I don't know and have nothing setup to test it.  You'll need to figure out what the class being returned is, find it's documentation and figure it out.  Best of luck!

Comment: Another question may be better, since it's much more specific now.

Comment: Thanks Nick you helped me and thank you for your time